# Module not found when I run migrate.py

Tags: python, flask

This problem has recently been affecting both my flask and Django applications, when I try "python migrate.py [any command]", I always get that some modules can not be found but when I check the code in VSCode, the modules are all present and the python version is not the problem and and even pip show [module] shows that the modules are installed. But when I run any migrate function, I get errors of the modules not existing. By the way I'm running python 12

```
PS C:\Users\MAIN_new\Desktop\Flask-Blog-master> python manage.py init 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MAIN_new\Desktop\Flask-Blog-master\manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_script import Manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_script'

PS C:\Users\MAIN_new\Desktop\Flask-Blog-master> pip show flask_script
Name: Flask-Script
Version: 2.0.6
Summary: Scripting support for Flask
Home-page: http://github.com/smurfix/flask-script
Author: Dan Jacob
Author-email: danjac354@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: C:\Users\MAIN_new\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
Requires: Flask
Required-by:
```

and in VScode:
[image: VScode window]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.  Where is the python binary?

Comment: Show us the output of this python command `python --version`

Comment: C:\Users\MAIN_new\Desktop\Flask-Blog-master>python --version
Python 3.11.4

Comment: that's odd, my visual studio is telling me it has been set to python 3.12

Comment: You're running python directly from the command line.  The version you selected inside VS does not matter in that context.